# Leer datos de un Dialog Personalizado generados en un Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-fragment

Al darle click al botón "Add Client" que se ve en la 1ra foto me genera un dialog (de un layout) donde ingresaré datos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estoy haciendo las pruebas para capturar esos datos con un Toast pero me lo retorna como nulo: "Agregado clientenull" (estoy probando solo con el campo Apellidos, aún no hago validaciones).

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Debuggeando me tope que me lanza este error:

> "SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length"

Encontré la posible solución que era agregando esta propiedad al EditText: android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"

Sin embargo me sigue botando el mismo error.

Este es mi porción de código.

```
public class Clientes extends Fragment {
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_clientes,container,false);
    Button btnAddClient = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.btnAddClient);

    EditText txtDNI = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.txtDNI);
    EditText txtRUC = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.txtRUC);
    final EditText txtApellidos = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.txtApellidos);
    EditText txtNombres = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.txtNombres);
    EditText txtDireccion = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.txtDireccion);

    btnAddClient.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
            LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
            builder.setTitle("Agregar Cliente");
            builder.setView(R.layout.dialog_clientes);
            builder.setPositiveButton("Agregar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Agregado cliente" + txtApellidos, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
            builder.show();
            builder.create();
        }
    });
    return view;
}
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

El mensaje 
que indicas es porque no obtienes correctamente el valor dentro del `EditText`.

> "Agregado clientenull"

Para obtener el valor especificado dentro del `EditText`, se realiza mediante el método **[getText()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/EditText.html#getText())**:

```
txtApellidos.getText().toString()
```

debe ser de esta forma:

```
 Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Agregado cliente: " + txtApellidos.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

---

En el caso tuyo mencionas que al obtener la referencia del `EditText` marca nullpointerException, te sugiero realizar un pequeño cambio. En lugar de usar directamente `setView()`, se obtiene la vista en la cual se obtendrían las referencias de los elementos mediante `findViewById()`:

```
...
...    
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
    builder.setTitle("Agregar Cliente");

    //obtiene la vista en la cual se buscaran los elementos.
    View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_clientes, null);
    //builder.setView(R.layout.dialog_clientes);
    builder.setView(dialogView);

    final EditText txtApellidos = (EditText) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.txtApellidos);

    builder.setPositiveButton("Agregar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Agregado cliente" + txtApellidos.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
...
...
```

Comment: Ya he intentado eso y me lanza un error "NullPointerException" -> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.text.Editable android.widget.EditText.getText()' on a null object reference

Comment: Ok  Juan ,  entonces el elemento no existe en el Layout que carga el Dialogo, agrego más información de como solucionar tu  problema.

Comment: El dialog_clientes.xml solo es layout, no tiene un archivo java. Desde fragment_clientes.xml llamo al dialog_clientes.xml a través del dialog. Cómo podría leer los datos ingresados?

Comment: oh! gracias por la explicación, ahora entiendo más sobre este detalle, es un poco raro como construiste el dialogo . en lugar de view usa getActivity() y dentro busca la referencia de la vista: final EditText txtApellidos = (EditText)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.txtApellidos);   me dices que resultado obtienes.

Comment: Al usar getActivity() en lugar de view me sigue botando el mismo resultado: "clientenull"... Tiene alguna otra forma de crear un dialogo personalizado?

Comment: Yo utilizaria un DialogFragment en lugar de un AlertDialog https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html

Comment: @JuanSánchez revisa mi actualización.

Comment: @Elenasys muchas gracias! Ya me funcionó! Mucha gente me recomendó usar un DialogFragment... Pondré en práctica eso para mejorar la app.

Comment: @JuanSánchez Excellente Juan!, esto también puede funcionar sin problema, ahora regularmente se usa DialogFragment sería buena opción usarlo. Saludos!.